# How to drop object accoring the object's name

Tags: r, rm

There are data.frame in R , I want to drop all of them whice name like 'table_*'.
`rm(c('table_a','table_j','table_w','table_z'))` seems can't work. Anyone can help ? Thanks

```
table_a <- data.frame(cat='a')
table_j <- data.frame(cat='b')
table_w <- data.frame(cat='c')
table_z <- data.frame(cat='d')
mapping_a <- data.frame(cat='d')
mapping_b <- data.frame(cat='d')

rm(c('table_a','table_j','table_w','table_z'))
```

Comment: Why are you doing this? Usually it is not necessary. Why are these data.frames not together in a list, which would make this easier?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the usual `rm(list = ls())` construct but additionally passing a `pattern` to `ls()` as the following:

```r
rm(list = ls(pattern = "^table_*"))
```